# Теряется табуляция при выводе текста из БД(MySQL)

Tags: вывод, php, sql

На скришоте ниже, видно, как потерялась табуляция, когда переносятся строки при выводе.
Текст выводится следующим образом:

```
<div id="site_page" class="main">
 <? echo $page['template']; // поле template из таблицы page ?>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Дамп таблички в студию, и способ выборки данных из базы. вы уверены что в бд у вас есть эта табуляция, и что при выборке из базы она тоже есть?)

Comment: В бд нет табуляции. А вот как задать ее то? Лучше конечно при выводе это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
<? echo $page['template']; // поле template из таблицы page ?>
```

На

```
<? echo "\t".$page['template']; // поле template из таблицы page ?>
```

Comment: @ToRcH565, сдвигается только первая строка. http://i.imgur.com/OznElT2.jpg

Comment: тогда так:

    echo "\t".str_replace("\n","\n\t",$page['template']);
или 

    echo "\t".str_replace("\r","\r\t",$page['template']);

непомню что из них(\r,\n) перевод строки

Comment: @ToRcH565, спасибо, такой вариант сработал >str_replace("\n","\n\t",$page['template'])

Comment: Значит верно подумал изначально... \n - new \r - return